# How prove $(\ln{\frac{1-\sin{xy}}{1+\sin{xy}}})^2 \geq \ln{\frac{1-\sin{x^2}}{1+\sin{x^2}}}\ln{\frac{1-\sin{y^2}}{1+\sin{y^2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How prove that if $x, y \in (0,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}})$ and $x \neq y$, then $(\ln{\frac{1-\sin{xy}}{1+\sin{xy}}})^2 \geq \ln{\frac{1-\sin{x^2}}{1+\sin{x^2}}}\ln{\frac{1-\sin{y^2}}{1+\sin{y^2}}}$?

Answer (score 0):

the right question is :

$(\ln{\dfrac{1-\sin{xy}}{1+\sin{xy}}})^2 \le \ln{\dfrac{1-\sin{x^2}}{1+\sin{x^2}}}\ln{\dfrac{1-\sin{y^2}}{1+\sin{y^2}}}$

$f(x)=\ln{\dfrac{1-\sin{x}}{1+\sin{x}}}\le 0 , f(0)=0$

WLOG $y=ax,a\ge1 \implies $the inequality $\iff (f(ax^2))^2 \le f(x^2)f(a^2x^2)  \iff (f(ax))^2 \le f(x)f(a^2x) \iff \dfrac{f(ax)}{f(x)} \le \dfrac{f(a^2x)}{f(ax)} $

$g(x)=\dfrac{f(ax)}{f(x)} \implies g(x) \le g(ax) \implies g'(x)> 0$

$g'(x)=\dfrac{2(\cos{(ax)}f(ax)-a\cos{x}f(x))}{\cos{x}\cos{(ax)}(fx)^2}$

$g'(x) >0\implies g_1(x)=\cos{(ax)}f(ax)-a\cos{x}f(x) \ge 0 $

$g'_1(x)=-a\sin{(ax)} f(ax)+a\cos{(ax)}f'(ax)+a\sin{x}f(x)-a\cos{x}f'(x)=a((\sin{x}f(x)-\cos{x}f'(x))-(\sin{(ax)} f(ax)-\cos{(ax)}f'(ax)))=a(g_2(x)-g_2(ax)) \\ g_2(x)=\sin{x}f(x)-\cos{x}f'(x)=\sin{x}f(x)+2$

$g'_2(x)=\cos{x}f(x) -2\tan{x}<0 \implies g_2(x) \ge g_2(ax) \implies g'_1(x) \ge 0$

$g_1(0)=0 \implies g_1(x)\ge 0$

the "=" will hold when $a=1$ or $x=0$